# Multiple CRUD system Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud

I want to build a CRUD system for multiple vendors to create their products in the database.

So far I have made it so a vendor can create, read, update, delete ALL products in the database. But what I want to do is each vendor should CRUD only the products he created. How can I achieve this?

The relationship between user and products is this:

In Product model:

```
public function user(){ 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
}
```

In User model:

```
public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
```

I am presenting the products like this:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $product->title }}</td>
      <td>{{ $product->description }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Should I use pivot tables or something? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Get all products authenticated user has created with single query:

```
$products = Product::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

And then iterate over products:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
```

**Option 2**

You can [`load()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) products:

```
auth()->user()->load('products');
```

And then iterate:

```
@foreach (auth()->user()->products as $product)
```

Comment: I don't have user_id in products table. Can I use something else? Or should I import this new field?

Comment: @daino92 you've shown the relationships which will not work without `user_id`. You should add it to the table and fill it with user ID when you're creating a new product. How else will you know the product belongs to the user?

Comment: You can create a migration to add this column and [foreign key](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) to existing table.

Comment: Add key like I edit above? Also how will I attach it?

Comment: No, you need to [add `user_id` to the table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns). If you have trouble with that I'd recommend you to read or watch some Eloquent relationships related tutorial or read Laravel docs.

Comment: Nop I'm ok with that. I have already added it. I meant about the foreign key you mentioned and also how the product will get the user id

Comment: You need to add a foreign key in a migration too. If you're asking about defining relationships, then no, you don't need to add foreign key to the definition if you're using conventions. When you're creating product you can just add user ID manually `Product::create(['name' => $name, 'user_id' => $userId])` or do the same using relationship `$user->products()->create(['name' => $name])`

Comment: Well I edit my migration like this:
`$table->integer('user_id');`
`$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');`
But I get this error: (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `
  products_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

Any idea?

Comment: It should be `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();`

Comment: Please create new question and add appropriate migrations source code and describe situation there.